# How do I make multiple queries in the same stored procedure in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, while-loop, schema, plpgsql

I need a stored procedure where I do two things. First I want to get all schema names that is prefixed with 'myschema_', so I've done this:

```
SELECT schema_name
FROM information_schema.schemata
WHERE schema_name LIKE 'myschema_%'
```

Next, I want a while loop that loops through each schema and gets 'name' from the 'person' table. This means that I somehow have to feed the result from the first select schema statement in as a parameter in the next call. And all of this should be one stored procedure.

This is what I want the stored procedure to return:

```
|  schema  | name |
-------------------
| schema_1 | Mike |
| schema_1 | Jane |
| schema_2 | Rich |
| schema_3 | Fred |
| schema_4 | Chris|
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Please add complete details about your problem

Comment: @AkhileshMishra What details am I missing?

Comment: In postgresql Procedure will not return any value. You have to write a function for it.

Comment: Ah got it, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need plpgsql block or procedure and dynamic SQL to do this.

```sql
create or replace function my_function()
returns table (sname text, pname text) as
$$
DECLARE
  running_schema text;
  running_name text;
  DYN_SQL constant text default 'select "name" from %I.person';
BEGIN
  for running_schema in --your query 
   SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name LIKE 'myschema_%'
  loop
    for running_name in execute format(DYN_SQL, running_schema) loop
       sname := running_schema;
       pname := running_name;
       return next;
    end loop;
  end loop;
END;
$$ language plpgsql;

-- Unit test
SELECT sname, pname from my_function();
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Not if the `SELECT` list of the query has only a single entry.

Comment: When I run this, it says:
ERROR:  no language specified
SQL state: 42P13

Comment: My omission. I have editted the answer, `$$ language plpgsql;` on the last line.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm I don't know if there is something I'm misunderstanding here, but I'm still not getting anything out of the stored procedure... It says that it's completed successfully, but I'm not getting the names out... I'm confused.. When I call the stored procedure from she server it says "No results were returned by the query."

Comment: Well, this is just the frame of your actual procedure (or function in case you want it to return something). Pls. add your program logic where the comments are. What do you expect to be returned?

Comment: @Stefanov.sm When I call the stored procedure I want the schema and person names returned. I've edited the post.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm Almost, now it returns the schema and the name, but in the same column separated by a comma. I just need them in separate columns then I'm done.

Comment: You do have them in separate columns - `sname` and `pname`. The function returns a table. Use `select * from my_function()` instead of `select my_function()` when you call it. You may also see the 'unit test' query.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm Aaaah I missed that part, it works perfectly!! Thank you very much, my problem is solved.